# Inline style on image, paragraphs won't wrap

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I've created a blog using Wordpress and am attempting to add images to each post. The images don't seem to work 'inline' though. I have attempted add inline styles (using Chrome dev tools) and cannot seem to get the paragraphs to wrap.

[Example](http://rubytuesdaycreative.co.uk/blog/)

Comment: Please post your problem code for the ages: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84342/answer-that-only-contains-a-link-to-jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For text to wrap around the image, you must have `display: inline` as well as a `float` set.

You have `display:inline` set on the div that contains the div that contains the caption and image, but no float applied.  Add `float: left` to the parent div of the caption div (the one that already has `display: inline` set as an inline style) and the text will flow around the image.

Or remove that parent div entirely (since it's totally extraneous and has no real purpose) and simply apply `display: inline` to the `.wp-caption` class that is applied to the caption div that contains the image and `float: left` to the `.alignleft` class (which is what WP assigns to any left-aligned image).

Answer (score 1):

Add a `float:left` to the `div` with classes `wp-caption alignleft`, like this:

```
.alignleft
{
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the div that surrounds the image and place the images inside the paragraph tag.  When the images is inside the `p` tags you can then align left/right and the text will flow around them.